# NT Authority/System can't see protected OS files

Tags: windows-10, console-application, scheduled-tasks, local-system-account

**The Question:**

Why can't the LocalSystem account (NT Authority\System) see files in the Recycle Bins or the Temporary Internet Files directory?

**Background:**

I created a scheduled task to run using the System account. The purpose of the task is to execute the Disk Cleanup Utility with predefined setting (for example: cleanmgr.exe sagerun:1). When it executes, it seems to run with no errors. But when I check the resources it's supposed to clean (Temporary Internet Files, Recycle Bin etc.), they're still there.

So I thought maybe cleaning up the two resources manually might work. I developed a console application in C# that clears the Recycle Bin and the Temporary Internet Files. I test it and it works just fine. But again, when I attempt to run it as a scheduled task with the System account, I run into the same issue again.

Following the log, it looks like when running the application with System account, it sees no files are in the Recycle Bin or the Temporary Internet Files directory.

Upon checking the Security tab for the Temporary Internet Files directory, it shows System as a full access account to that directory.

I'm so puzzled by this issue. I may be missing something but I assumed the LocalSystem account has the highest privilege on a machine. Is that not the case?

Comment: those folders are per user - so the system account is cleaning it up for itself.

Comment: @DanielA.White Oh ok. Thank you. That makes sense. Is it possible to for a System account to go through all users' Temporary Internet Files and Recycle Bins to clear them?

Comment: it looks like you adjust the sagerun to be different: https://www.howtogeek.com/256594/how-to-enable-hidden-options-in-windows-disk-cleanup-tool/